# R JSONlite: How to extract below output?

Tags: r, web-scraping, jsonlite

*See the below R code, I'm using JSONlite package to scrape data from a website:*

```
>url <- "http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/"

>a<-fromJSON(paste0(url, 1))

>a
```

*Gives me following output:*

```
$id
[1] 1

$photo
[1] "59936.jpg"

$web_name
[1] "Szczesny"

$event_explain
list()

$fixture_history
$fixture_history$all
list()

$fixture_history$summary
list()


$season_history
     [,1]      [,2]   [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17]

[1,] "2008/09" "0"    "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "45"  "0"  

[2,] "2009/10" "0"    "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "45"  "0"  

[3,] "2010/11" "1350" "0"  "0"  "6"  "19" "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"   "0"   "45"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "43"  "62" 

[4,] "2011/12" "3420" "0"  "0"  "13" "49" "0"  "1"  "0"  "2"   "0"   "82"  "8"   "469" "0"   "59"  "139"

[5,] "2012/13" "2250" "0"  "0"  "10" "24" "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"   "0"   "71"  "3"   "314" "0"   "53"  "102"

[6,] "2013/14" "3330" "0"  "0"  "16" "41" "0"  "1"  "0"  "2"   "0"   "113" "4"   "475" "194" "59"  "157"

[7,] "2014/15" "1498" "0"  "0"  "3"  "21" "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"   "0"   "44"  "0"   "172" "215" "52"  "47"
```

*Now I want to access the season_history data as a data-frame or matrix for analysis, how to go about it? I desire a final output with headers:*

*1.web_name*

*2.$season_history[1,17]*

*That is : Szcezesny 47*

Comment: Is your use of these data in compliance with the website terms and conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the difficulty. Wouldn't it just be:

```
as.data.frame(a$season.history)
```

Comment: Yup thanks, working! I'm naive. I'm decent at SAS. Can you recommend where to learn R?

Comment: How about the [SO R Tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) for starters?

Comment: "Introduction to R" is mandatory. The canonical text for SAS users is probably Bob Muenchen's with a title something along the lines of "R for SAS and SPSS Users". I thought that Andrie deVries's and Joris Meys' "R for Dummies" was quite good, but full disclosure, I got it as a review copy. I did buy Norm Matloff's "Art of R Programming" and also thought it was good. I did not like "The R Book" because I thought it presented the R object model very sloppily and encouraged a lot of bad habits.